# Chinese Teapot inscription

Tags: simplified-characters

[image]

I am trying to find out more about this teapot, near the bottom there is an inscription in what looks like chinese. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's "鉄鋳". It means "It's made of metal."  鉄 means metal.

They are another kind of (simplified) traditional Chinese characters(铁铸). some people may say they are Japanese kanji, but you know kanji(汉字) are from China.

Chinese characters have different shape in different period, in different area, such as Hongkong and Taiwan.